# Turn off auto increment for ID's and replace with custom value from API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Pulling in data from an API and populating my database with said data. All fields in database are populating as they should, except the ID field which is auto incrementing. Need to turn this off as I am relying on the ID from the API to operate most of my site.

Google around and tried using this

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute()]
```

didnt do anything though....

This is how i am recieving my data from the API call, all checks out:

```
[{"id":"40387124","name":"Abyss Flower","type":"Normal Monster","desc":"A rarely seen flower that blossoms quietly on the edge of darkness.","atk":"750","def":"400","level":"2","race":"Plant","attribute":"EARTH","card_images":[{"id":"40387124","image_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/40387124.jpg","image_url_small":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_small/40387124.jpg"}],"card_prices":{"cardmarket_price":"0.00","tcgplayer_price":"0.00","ebay_price":"10.99","amazon_price":"0.00"}}]
```

however, my table is populating like so:

```
19  Abyss Flower    750 400 A rarely seen flower that blossoms quietly on the edge of darkness. 2   Normal Monster  EARTH
```

instead of 19, which is the auto incremented ID generate from the database, I need to be able to accept the ID from the API, 40387124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Key attribute with the database generated option:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

or if you are using fluentAPI then like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Comment: hmmm this just threw me an error saying  Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Cards' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Chances are it is due to the migration of an Identity key to this non generated key. Take a look at this blog post for more information: https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/